# Инициализация динамического массива структур в Си

Tags: c

Вот код:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct Sentence {
    char* chars;
};

struct Sentence get_sentence(char* chars){
    struct Sentence s;
    char sentence_chars[strlen(chars) + 1];
    strcpy(sentence_chars, chars);
    s.chars = sentence_chars;
    return s;
}
int main() {
    struct Sentence* sentences = malloc(sizeof(struct Sentence) * 5);
    sentences[0] = get_sentence("hello");
    sentences[1] = get_sentence("world");

    printf("%s ", sentences[0].chars);
    printf("%s", sentences[1].chars);
    return 0;
}
```

На экран будут выведены одинаковые значения. Почему и как можно этого избежать?

Comment: А куда вы копируете строку? Вы же не выделяете под нее память

Comment: У вас там указатель, а не массив.

Comment: Разве если я сохраню строковые литералы в переменные, а затем передам в функцию get_sentence что - то изменится?

Comment: так массив или указатель это неважно

Comment: В обеих вызовах в структурах будет возвращен указатель на одну и ту же память. Последнее ее содержимое будет напечатано. Только у вас серьезная ошибка -- вы возвращаете адрес локальной переменной в функции, т.е. память, содержимое которой не сохраняется межде вызовами функции. Если вы видите осмысленный вывод, то это случайность. Для исправления напишите (вместо почти всего кода в функции) `s.chars = strdup(chars);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Почему одинаковые?**

Потому что вам так везло, что временная переменная `char sentence_chars` оказывалась по одному и тому же адресу.

Если бы между вызовами `get_sentence` были другие функции, то `sentence_chars` оказалась в другом месте, а значение из первого вызова затерлось мусором из стека.

**Как избежать?**

Выделяйте память с помощью `calloc`/`malloc`.

И не забывайте ее освобождать, используя `free`.